# Google Sheets Query by Date and Group missing data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to query a data set by date and return ID's that are not listed in the queried date range as compared to a master list. I have set up this [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WtjPF-ObjILH9XC8lvPpou0UX_-BCxQM3xZ3WQkCKYE/edit?usp=sharing) as an example.

I know and understand how to use the query function to select data by the dates:

`=query(Datasheet!$A$2:$B,"Select B where A > date '"&TEXT('Querysheet'!$A$3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and A <= date '"&TEXT('Querysheet'!$B$3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ...")`

The part that I am missing is how to compare and return a group of ID's that are missing from the Datasheet compared with the Mastersheet.

Comment: I am looking for the exact opposite of the results from this formula for the date range 1/27/2021-2/1/2021. '=unique(query(Datasheet!$A$2:$B,"Select B where A > date '"&TEXT(Querysheet!$A$3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and A <= date '"&TEXT(Querysheet!$B$3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))' The results should be 4444, 6666, 7777, 8888, 9999

Comment: Have you tried using array formulas?

Comment: I have not yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Mastersheet!A2:A, NOT(COUNTIF(UNIQUE(QUERY(Datasheet!A2:B, 
 "select B 
  where A >  date '"&TEXT(Querysheet!A3, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date '"&TEXT(Querysheet!B3, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")), Mastersheet!A2:A))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have placed it into the test spreadsheet that I shared and it returns the error "VLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range."

Comment: Here is what the formula looks like that produces that error: '=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(Datasheet!A2:A, QUERY(Datasheet!$A$2:$B,"Select B where A > date '"&TEXT(Querysheet!$A$3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and A <= date '"&TEXT(Querysheet!$B$3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"), {1,2}, 0)))'

Comment: Thanks again for the help! You were awesome!